# Share debian package maintainer scripts and conffiles from existing package to a new package

Tags: debian, packaging, dpkg

I have creating two variation of debian packages for python2 and python3. I already have com.python2.package1 created with all of it is maintainer scripts. Now I am try to add com.python3.package2 so my debian/control file is like

```
Package: com.python2.package1
Name: Example Package1
Description: An example package1.
This longer description will load when a depiction URL is not specified.
Author: Ms. Example <example@example.com>
Maintainer: Example, Inc. <example-inc@example.com>
Version: 1.0-1
Section: Addons (SpringBoard)
Pre-Depends: com.example.system
Depends: com.example.library

Package: com.python3.package2
Name: Example Package2
Description: An example package2.
This longer description will load when a depiction URL is not specified.
Author: Ms. Example <example@example.com>
Maintainer: Example, Inc. <example-inc@example.com>
Version: 1.0-2
Section: Addons (SpringBoard)
Pre-Depends: com.example.system
Depends: com.example.library
```

Now com.python2.package1 already have the maintainer scripts and conffiles in the debian directory. How can I make com.python3.package2 use same files so that I don't have to create extra copies for each variation?

May be **override_dh_installdeb** is used to do that but how does it accomplishes this task?

Comment: Same source packages? Every package must have the maintainer scripts: you never know in which order the packages are installed. You may `require` the other packages, and call the maintainer script from your scripts.

Comment: I would like to have scripts in debian/ directory and then  override_dh_installdeb should install the same scripts for both packages. So both of the packages have their own scripts once they are built but they are collected from the same source files...

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this in `debian/rules`:

```
override_dh_install:
        dh_install
        install debian/source/update.py debian/com.python2.package1/usr/lib/python2/dist-packages/my-package/
```

I'm assuming you include the script already in the `debian/com.python3.package2.install` file and just need to copy it a second time into the `com.python2.package1` package.

I'm also assuming that by "maintainer scripts" you mean Python egg/module maintainer scripts, (`__init__.py` kind of thing), not Debian package maintainer scripts (`*.postinst`).

Comment: Thanks. com.python2.package1 Is already created I am just adding com.python3.package2 to it. By maintainer scripts I meant debian maintainer script. 

So in short I already had a  com.python2.package1 and I am just trying to create com.python3.package2 variant of it that shares the same conffiles and debian maintainer scripts from the existing one.

Comment: For things like `com.python3.package2.postinst`, just don't. You can try to use symlinks or hardlinks in the debian directory, but that's just not going to survive git, or dpkg-buildpackage will choke on it, or something else will break.  You can look in the final `debian/<pkgname>/DEBIAN` directory and try to copy files into place there, but that's going behind debhelper's back.  You're better off just making a copy and moving on.  I get trying to honor DRY here, but the effort isn't worth it.  The best option is to stop supporting python2. :)

Comment: I already can use git symlinks but I would like to use the build process itself for a better solution.
I agree the best option is to stop supporting python2 but in bigger systems it is not that trivial to remove the support so one needs to have a transition period inbetween